# Model, total entry count

Tags: django, django-models

Good evning! Is there a way to get the total entry count in a django model without counting the entries? I'm afraid this is inefficient with large datasets...  Something along the lines of what a database does to deliver autoincrementing IDs?

Edit: I'm only interested in a rough estimate of the figure, and deletions will be very infrequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean about inefficiency. Databases are highly optimised, with indexes, to do things like counting. This:

```
MyModel.objects.count()
```

translates to a simple `SELECT COUNT(...)` which is as efficient as it gets. You can't simply take the highest autoincremented ID, as that takes no account of deleted records: it's perfectly possible for there to be only a single row in the table, but for that row to have an ID in the millions or billions.

Comment: I only need a rough esimate of the figure in a database with very few exepected deletions, but i suppose you are right